# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

Tags: websocket, socket.io, serversocket

Please help me, thank so much!!!!

In my localhost did walk perfectly but now I got all on my server to see how it works online and it has an problem.

```
GET https://mydomain.io:8890/socket.io/?userid=5b344be12820260db552b202&room=5c347250ac210c52bc542f12&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MYV9V2s net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

debug=socket.io* node server.js

```
[root@litespeed public_html]# debug=socket.io* node server.js
Express server listening on port 8890
{ message: 'in',
  sender: '5b344be12820260db552b202',
  message_id: '5c526142ac210c415f5422e2' }
{ message: 'sdasd',
  sender: '5b344be12820260db552b202',
  receive: '5c36f45fac210c6cd07f0b32',
  message_id: '5c526142ac210c415f5422e2' }
```

**Info server**

- Npm version 6.5.0
- Open port 8890
- node v 11.8.0
- socket.io
- Redis 5.0.3 (00000000/0) 64 bit - Running in standalone mode - Port: 6379

I don't know how to resolve this error

Here is my server code - server.js

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require("fs");
var https = require("https");
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
var users = {};

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.io/fullchain.pem')
};


var express = require("express");
var app = express();


var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(8890, function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + 8890);
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("New connect");
    var userId = socket.handshake.query.userid;
    var room = socket.handshake.query.room;
    socket.join(room);
    if (userId in users) {
        //fail
        console.log('Already exist');
    } else {
        console.log("Added");
        users[userId] = socket;
    }

    //disconnect
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log(socket.id + ': disconnect');
        delete users[userId];
    });

});

redis.subscribe('chat', 'focus', function (err, count) {
    // Now we are subscribed to both the 'news' and 'music' channels.
    // `count` represents the number of channels we are currently subscribed to.
});

redis.on("message", function (channel, message) {
    var message = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(message);
    if (channel == 'chat') {
        var receive = message.receive;
        var sender = message.sender;
        var senderSocket = users[sender] || null;
        var receiveSocket = users[receive] || null;
        if (receiveSocket) {
            receiveSocket.join(message.message_id);
        }
        if (senderSocket) {
            senderSocket.join(message.message_id);
//        io.to(users[message.receive].id).emit(channel, message);
            io.to(message.message_id).emit(channel, message);
            console.log("Message was succefully sent!");
        }
    } else if (channel == 'focus') {
        var senderSocket = users[message.sender] || null;
        if (senderSocket) {
            senderSocket.broadcast.to(message.message_id).emit(channel, message);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my client code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var userid = '5b344be12820260db552b202';//anything you like
    var room = '5c347250ac210c52bc542f12';//anything you like
    var socket = io.connect('https://mydomain.io:8890', {query: "userid=" + userid + "&room=" + room});
    socket.on('chat', function (data) {
        console.log('123455');
        var owner = '5b344be12820260db552b202';
        $("#last-msg-" + data.message_id).html(data.message);
        var clone_elem = $('#' + data.message_id).clone();
        $('#' + data.message_id).remove();
        if (owner == data.sender) {
            $("#new-message-" + data.message_id).append('<div class="line pull-right clearfix"><span>' + data.message + '</span></div>');
        } else {
            $("#new-message-" + data.message_id).append('<div class="line pull-left clearfix"><span>' + data.message + '</span></div>');
            if (data.message_id != '5c347250ac210c52bc542f12') {
                clone_elem.addClass('no-read');
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/site/read',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "id=" + data.message_id,
                    success: function (data) {
                    }
                });
            }
            document.getElementById("audio-" + data.receive).play();
        }
        $('ul.list-group').prepend(clone_elem);
        scrollBottom();
    });
    socket.on('focus', function (data) {
        if ('5c347250ac210c52bc542f12' == data.message_id) {
            if (data.message == 'in') {
                $("#chatting").show();
            } else if (data.message == 'out') {
                $("#chatting").hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Redis connect

```
'redis' => [
            'class' => 'yii\redis\Connection',
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 6379,
            'database' => 0
        ],
```